# How to prevent Emacs from writing temporary .# files?

Tags: emacs, temporary-files

My Emacs writes temporary files which start with `.#`. For example when I am ediging `foo.cljs` Emacs sometimes creates a `.#foo.cljs` file. How to prevent this?

Background: I am using [Spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org) for ClojureScript development. While editing files the build tool ([boot](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot-clj)) watches these, compiles them and sends updates to the browser. Sadly it crashes from time to time because of this temporary files coming and going.

Comment: Related question: [Why does emacs create temporary symbolic links for modified files?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738170/why-does-emacs-create-temporary-symbolic-links-for-modified-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(setq create-lockfiles nil)
```

does the trick.